# Disable options between 2 multi selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have this situation:

2 Multi Selects with the same number of options and the same values:

```
<select id="first" name="first" multiple>
     <option value="1" id="1">First</option>
     <option value="2" id="2">Second</option>
     <option value="3" id="3">Third</option>
</select>

<select id="second" name="second" multiple>
     <option value="1" id="1">First</option>
     <option value="2" id="2">Second</option>
     <option value="3" id="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

If I **select** a element in the first one, I have to **disable** it in the second one. If I **deselect** a element in the first one, I have to **active** (not select) it in the second one. The same situation for the **second select**.

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: You have (at least) two elements sharing each of the numerical `id`s. This is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty trivial to achieve.

What have you tried so far?

As rough outline:

Bind a function to the change event on each select field, and create a function to update the other drop down based on the selected values of the first. Depending on what you're doing some server side validation may also be advisable in case a user has javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#first, #second").change(function(){
   var index;
   for (var i = 0; i < $(this).find("option").length; i++){
      if ($(this).find("option").eq(i).attr("selected") == true){
         index = i;
         break;
      }
   }
   if (index){
      var target = ($(this).attr("id") == "first") ? $("#second) : $("#first");
      $(target).find("option").eq(index).attr("disabled", true); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You must have unique ID's.** I suggest using classes instead of ID, like `class="opt1"`, etc...

About the jQuery behaviour, try this:

```
var $select = $('select');
$select.on('change', function () {
    $select.find('option').attr('disabled', false);
    var selectedValue = this.value;
    $('select').not(this).find('option').filter(function () {
        return this.value == selectedValue
    }).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H7MCY/)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bkDX3/

```
<select id="first" name="first" multiple onchange="selectedItem(this, this.value)">
    <option value="1" id="1">First</option>
    <option value="2" id="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">Third</option>
</select>

<select id="second" name="second" multiple onchange="selectedItem(this, this.value)">
    <option value="1" id="1">First</option>
    <option value="2" id="2">Second</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">Third</option>
</select>

<script>
function selectedItem(dropdown, value) {
    var changed = (dropdown.id == 'first') ? 'second' : 'first';
    if (value == '') {
        document.getElementById(changed).disabled = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(changed).disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the two elements a class, e.g. `mutual-exclude`. Then:

```
$(".mutual-exclude").change(function () {
    var $other = $(".mutual-exclude").not(this);
    $(this).children("option").each(function () {
        $other.find("[value='" + this.value + "']").prop('disabled', this.selected);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bkDX3/7/)

Comment: @Krishna It does for me. I click First in column 1, First in column 2 becomes inactive. Then I click Second in column 1, First in column 2 becomes active and Second in column 2 is inactive.

Comment: A lot of overhead for a simple task. No jQuery function left out ;-)

Comment: @SplitYourInfinity Maybe true, but it has the advantage that it works.

Comment: Sorry, haven't played with that plugin, don't know offhand.

Answer (score 0):

Throwing my hat into the ring with another pure DOM solution. I think this is what you are trying to do. . ?

given the provided HTML (and changing the ids so that it's valid :) )

```
<select id="first" name="first" multiple="true" onchange="toggle();">
     <option value="1" id="1a">First</option>
     <option value="2" id="2a">Second</option>
     <option value="3" id="3a">Third</option>
</select>

<select id="second" name="second" multiple="true" onchange="toggle();">
     <option value="1" id="1b">First</option>
     <option value="2" id="2b">Second</option>
     <option value="3" id="3b">Third</option>
</select>


function toggle() {
    var a = document.getElementById("first").options;
    var b = document.getElementById("second").options;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        b[i].disabled = a[i].selected;
        a[i].disabled = b[i].selected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [NO jQuery or HTML change needed](http://jsfiddle.net/25PKa/4)

Here is "pure javascript" solution (works with jQuery also). Just drop this in your unload handler and done.

```
// Find the selectboxes
var first = document.getElementById("first");
var second = document.getElementById("second");

function attach(source, target) {
    source.onchange = function (e) { // Subsribe to the onchange event
        target.value = ""; // Disable the selection in the other selectbox
        for (var i = 0; i < source.children.length; i++) { // Loop over all the options
             // Enable all the options for the source selectbox
            source.children[i].disabled = false;
            // Disable the selected source option (if any) on the target side
            target.children[i].disabled = i === (source.value && (parseInt(source.value, 10) - 1)); 
        }
    };
}

// Bind both selectboxes to each other
attach(first, second);
attach(second, first);
```

To see it in action check out this **[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/25PKa/4)**.